# How to install LAPACK for MSVS 2010 on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, cmake, lapack

I am using the ITPP library [(IT++ library)](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/) for one of my projects. For using the eigen_sym() function of this library, it asks for installing the LAPACK. I tried the direct prebuilt libraries for Windows but still get the error. Finally on the following site:

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries

I found a solution under "Build Instructions to create LAPACK and LAPACKE 3.5.0 dlls for Windows with MinGW" that might work. I did steps 1 to 5 but got stuck 6 onwards.

My destination of the cmake build is `E:/LAPACK`

I got an error while in the cmd prompt while entering:

```
cd E:/LAPACK 3.5.0 >Enter
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe >Enter
```

i'm getting

```
mingw32-make.exe> No targets specified and no make file found. Stop.
```

Can someone explain the step 6 onwards in detail and tell me where i'm going wrong?
I finally want to get the `.dll` and `.lib` files.

Comment: Why are you building with gcc/mingw if you want Visual Studio 2010 support? I build lapack with Visual Studio.

Comment: Bcoz it is said on the page that the .dlls and .libs will work if MinGW/bin is added in the system path

Comment: I guess the problem is you do not have a fortran compiler. I made a mistake I build clapack which does not require that.

Comment: The other .libs and .dlls dont work

Comment: Anyways I assume you are typing make and get the "No targets specified and no make file found. Stop." Because pressing enter in a command window will not generate this error.

Comment: Did you configure with cmake and generate with the generator being for mingw makefiles and not Visual Studio? You do not want Visual Studio to use mingw.

Comment: I've configured and generated. The problem comes after that in the cmd prompt part.

Comment: I do cd E:/lapack-3.5>Enter       then      C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe>Enter    and get the error of no targets and no makefile found

Comment: If the configuration / generation worked you would not get this error because the process generates a makefile. So either you selected the wrong generator in Cmake-gui or cmake failed to generate. Or you are looking in the wrong folder for your makefile.

Comment: You mean E:/lapack-3.5 has a Makefile?

Comment: It would be kind of you if you could tell me the entire process cmd prompt onwards

Comment: I believe you are using the correct process. I am unsure how mingw-make is not finding the Makefile although I do not use that often.

Comment: You mentioned a different path in your question versus the comments. Is the makefile in "E:/LAPACK 3.5.0" or "E:/lapack-3.5". Are you changing directory to the one that has the makefile?

Comment: You can have a look at the steps I followed on [link](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/#libraries) and tell me if it's wrong or where I might be going wrong. I'm using a win32 machine.

Comment: The steps look reasonable to me. I will try them in a few hours if I get a chance and no one has found the solution.

Comment: I got it to build without much difficulty. The key was making sure that you do not set the build folder in cmake to the same folder as the source. I installed the source tree in X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0 and set the build folder to X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0\build. Then after I configured with CMake I ran mingw32-make from the build folder not the source folder. There is a Makefile in the source folder but that does not work by default.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to build LAPACK 3.5 for windows using mingw and pretty much the build guide from the LAPACK page. Using the following steps

1. Download lapack.tgz from here http://netlib.org/lapack/lapack.tgz
2. Extract to a folder. I used 7zip file manager to extract the tarball to x:/Other/test
3. Install mingw32. I used this: http://www.mingw.org/download/installer and I selected and installed **mingw32-developer-toolkit** + **mingw32-base** + **mingw32-gfortran** + **mingw32-gcc-g++** + **msys-base**
4. Open a command prompt
5. Append mingw to your path

   path=C:/Mingw/bin;%PATH%

   change directory to the location you extracted lapack: For me this was X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0 so the command I typed was the following (your path will be different):

   C:\Users\jdrescher>x:
   X:>cd Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0
   X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0>

   make a folder for your build. I used build

   X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0>mkdir build

   then change directory to the build folder

   X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0>cd build
   X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0\build>

   Now configure with CMake

   X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0\build>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D CMAKE_GNUtoMS=ON ..

   Now use gnu make to build LAPACK

   X:\Other\Test\lapack-3.5.0\build>c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe

   **Note: This step will take several minutes.**

After the above steps completed 100% with no errors, I have the following dlls in the build\bin folder: **libblas.dll**, **liblapack.dll**, **libtmglib.dll**

Also the following libraries, and exp files in the build\lib folder: **libblas.exp**, **libblas.lib**, **liblapack.exp**, **liblapack.lib**, **libtmglib.exp** and **libtmglib.lib**.

Comment: I would recommend using [minGW64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) instead, mingGW is not as well maintained as mingw64 and despite its name it does have 32bit compilers.

Comment: I will test that later. Possibly adjusting my instructions.