# How to get LAPACK working in 64 bit windows with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, lapack

I am currently using LAPACK 3.5.0 for Visual Studio C/C++ 2012. To install this I followed the instructions given in the answer to this question:

[How to install LAPACK for MSVS 2010 on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283657/how-to-install-lapack-for-msvs-2010-on-windows)

I then proceeded to link the BLAS and LAPACK libraries in "Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies" and I copied and pasted the .dll files to the folder where my .exe is located.

After doing this, the 32 bit version of my program works as expected. However the 64 bit version won't compile. I get the following error:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>PIC_effective_index.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol dstevx_
```

Basically, what I tried to get the 64 bit version to work was to mimic what I did for the 32 bit version.

Is anybody able to correct me on where I am going wrong?