# Build Lapack, Blas (netlib) for VS, windows

Tags: windows, cmake, makefile, lapack, blas

for build i use bash on Ubuntu on Windows. I want to use these libraries for my c++ project using extern "C". I have already looked all over the internet and the whole internet, but most of the questions are old and do not work, please help me.

I followed this question: [How to install LAPACK for MSVS 2010 on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283657/how-to-install-lapack-for-msvs-2010-on-windows)

What am I doing:

```
mkdir lap
cd lap
git clone https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack.git
cd lapack
mkdir mybuild
cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -D CMAKE_GNUtoMS=ON -S ./ -B ./mybuild
cd mybuild
make
```

And after assembly there are no dlls, no bin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzBIM.png)

And in the lib folder there is not even .a or .lib libraries
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDy2t.png)

Please help me to understand.

Comment: "I use bash on Ubuntu on Windows" - Do you mean that you use Ubuntu via **WSL**? In that case it builds the project (LACACK) suitable for Ubuntu, not for Windows. For build for Windows, you need to use Windows command prompt (or its alternatives).

Comment: @Tsyvarev ok, tell me the steps to build lapack for windows please

Comment: The steps are written in the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289629/3440745). Just follow them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev if i do it with mingw can i use them in visual studio? it mingw?